# Log Messages in Hive UDF

Tags: hadoop, logging, hive

I want to write a log messages in a file for Hive UDF using log4j.

I have written a simple UDF which is working as per expectations and able to write log messages in a file locally.

But when i tried to test the udf in hive shell on Hadoop cluster , it is not able to write log messages in file.

Below is the code:

```
package com.log4j.example;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    public class isNull extends UDF {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(isNull.class.getName());

    public Boolean evaluate(String input) {
    Object in = input;
    boolean returnType = false;
        if (in == null) {
            log.debug("Input is Null"+in);
            returnType = true;
        } else {
            returnType = false;
        }
        return returnType;

    }}
    Below is the properties file for log4j
#TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, toConsole, toFile

#CONSOLE
log4j.appender.toConsole=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.toConsole.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toConsole.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] - %c.%M - %m%n

#DAILYROLLINGFILE
log4j.appender.toFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.toFile.File=/idn/home/test/logfile.log
#log4j.appender.toFile.Append=false
log4j.appender.toFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy`enter code here`-MM-dd
log4j.appender.toFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] - %c.%M - %m%n
```

Can anyone help me why above configured code is not write log messages in file on specified path?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: What do you mean by "locally"?? Hive queries run a **distributed** processing job, scattered on multiple machines, and each Mapper or Reducer runs in a volatile container. So your UDF can only write in a *temp* directory which will be nixed when the container stops.

Comment: You have two ways to do what you want, but either is WAY MORE COMPLEX than your naive attempt: _(a)_ generate a unique file name and log your stuff to HDFS, then try to make sense of the multiple files created by your query; or _(b)_ start a Flume agent on a specific machine, add the Log4J/Flume JAR to your Hive session, send all your logs to the Flume agent which can then merge the logs to a local file.

Comment: Locally means UDF is executed through Junit in eclipse and able to write the logs at mentioned path.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up for the question which I asked above.

1. Did the some changes in my properties file like below:

   ```
   log4j.rootLogger= FATAL,file

   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
   log4j.appender.file.File=/idn/home/sshivhar/Sanjeev_POC/log/application_new
   log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
   ```

   I changed the **logging level to FATAL** because I was looking for only those messages which I wrote inside my UDF.

   Because logging messages has below priority level:

   ```
   TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL
   ```

   If I changed the **`FATAL` to `INFO`**, it will also write the unwanted `WARN` and `ERROR` messages into the file which comes from hive shell like mapper,reducer information. Similarly, `DEBUG` will write `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`, `FATAL` messages.
2. Changed the `log.debug` to `log.fatal` inside the HIVE UDF. Rest of the code is same as above.
3. Passed the property file to hive shell using hiveconf parameter while entering like below:

   ```
   hive -hiveconf hive.log4j.file=/path/log4jprop.properties
   ```

   Ran below commands:

   ```
   ADD JAR path
   CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION udfName as 'class_path'
   select udfName(col) from table;
   ```

   Log file will get created on a daily basis and can be customize as per need.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that the udf jar file is copied over the cluster and exected by each node, hence if the path is valid and the user have permission to write, a log file is written in each machine.